# Django serving media files (user uploaded files ) in openshift

Tags: python, django, openshift, django-media

I have successfully deployed my Django project in openshift. But I need to be able to serve files that are uploaded by users. I user MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL for that. I followed [this](http://masci.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/serving-django-media-files-in-openshift/) tutorial here, but nothing happened. I had to change MEDIA_ROOT because the one suggested there isn't correct i think. So my MEDIA_ROOT looks like

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR', ''),'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I added the .htaccess in /wsgi folder with as it says in the article

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^application/media/(.+)$ /static/$1 [L]
```

and created the build script to make symbolic link of the media in static as the article says.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media ]; then
    mkdir $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media
fi

ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static/media
```

In my urls.py I have added the

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

but I still can't serve them. I also tried not to include the django static method in urls.py but the same result.

In [another](http://appsembler.com/blog/paas-bakeoff-comparing-stackato-openshift-dotcloud-and-heroku-for-django-hosting-and-deployment/) tutorial .htacces is placed inside static folder. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: not able to solve my issue yet...Though it is clearly described that it works...

Comment: What is the goal? If you would like to be served the media files by Apache you shouldn't use urlpatterns (mostly in production). In the other case you shouldn't use rewrites and symlink (mostly for development).

Comment: Small note. On your URLS you have urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)

but it should be

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

The arguments are in reverse order

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for others to know, I solved my problem by correcting the RewriteRule adding media folder to the second part of the rule, so it became

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^application/media/(.+)$ /static/media/$1 [L]
```

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your media url. The symlink is created at wsgi/static/media, then your MEDIA_URL need is MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

First step, on build script .openshift/action_hooks/build:

```
if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media ]; then mkdir $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media fi

ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/media $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static/media
```

Second step:
In your settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

if ON_PAAS:
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'), 'media')
else: 
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem but Apostolos' solution above hasn't solved the issue: when I try to access `http://<domain>/media/<file>` it still doesn't work.

However it does work in another way. if I try to access the same file as if it was a static using `http://<domain>/static/media/<file>` then it does work. This happens even without employing Gpzim98's workaround. I think the reason is simply that the media files are now accessible through the symbolic link. In other words media files don't get served but you can now pretend they are static files.

Would be very keen to understand what is going on and how to resolve this problem fully (if it can be done) and be able to serve media files directly through the MEDIA_URL.

Thanks