# how serve django media file in shared hosting?

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, passenger, django-media

im using django **1.11.4** and i want to serve django media file in a shared host

my web server is **apache**

i already set `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` and evreything is fine when `Debug = True`

i alread try [HelioHost wiki](http://wiki.helionet.org/Django#Getting_started_with_Django_1.11) and [Django serving media files (user uploaded files ) in openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807969/django-serving-media-files-user-uploaded-files-in-openshift) but it dosnt work

Comment: you may want to configure your server for that. [Read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Comment: yes but i dont have permission to do it.

Comment: which hosting provider you are hosted with ?